# Alternative ways to parse this text? With less code as possible

Tags: c#, parsing

I have this text, that I would like to parse to get the names of the persons.
What is the easiest way to parse? Is there some tool/language or extension to C# language that allow me to catch this structure?

I know I can use some Split in C#, but I would like to hear from you experts another way, more dynamic and fluent of doing this.

The result can be, if possible, a class, with List of Countries, List of Function, List of names, maybe a structured dynamic/expando object.

```
 Country,
     Goleiros 
         [list of names]
     Defensores
         [list of names]
```

> Brasil
>
> Goleiros: Julio César (Toronto FC-CAN), Jefferson (Botafogo-BRA) e
>   Victor (Atlético Mineiro-BRA)
>
> Defensores: Thiago Silva (Paris Saint-Germain-FRA), David Luiz
>   (Chelsea-ING), Dante (Bayern de Munique-ALE), Henrique (Napoli-ITA),
>   Daniel Alves (Barcelona-ESP), Maicon (Roma-ITA), Marcelo (Real
>   Madrid-ESP) e Maxwell (Paris Saint-Germain-FRA)
>
> Meio-campistas: Luiz Gustavo (Wolfsburg-ALE), Paulinho
>   (Tottenham-ING), Ramires (Chelsea-ING), Fernandinho (Manchester
>   City-ING), Hernanes (Inter de Milão-ITA), Oscar (Chelsea-ING) e
>   Willian (Chelsea-ING)
>
> Atacantes: Hulk (Zenit-RUS), Bernard (Shakhtar Donetsk-UCR), Fred
>   (Fluminense-BRA), Jô (Atlético Mineiro-BRA) e Neymar (Barcelona-ESP)
>
> Técnico: Luiz Felipe Scolari (BRA)
>
> Croácia
>
> Goleiros: Stipe Pletikosa (Rostov-RUS), Danijel Subasic (Monaco-FRA) e
>   Oliver Zelenika (Lokomotiv Zagreb-CRO)
>
> Defensores: Darijo Srna (Shakhtar Donetsk-UCR), Domagoj Vida (Dínamo
>   de Kiev-UCR), Sime Vrsaljko (Genoa-ITA), Ivan Strinic (Dnipro-UCR),
>   Danijel Pranjic (Panathinaikos-GRE), Vedran Corluka (Lokomotiv
>   Moscou-RUS), Dejan Lovren (Southampton-ING), Gordon Schindelfeld
>   (Panathinaikos-GRE) e Igor Bubnjic (Udinese-ITA)
>
> Meio-campistas: Luka Modric (Real Madrid-ESP), Ivan Rakitic
>   (Sevilla-ESP), Mateo Kovacic (Inter de Milão-ITA), Niko Kranjcar
>   Queens Park Rangers-ING), Marcelo Brozovic (Dínamo Zagreb-CRO), Ognjen
>   Vukojevic (Dínamo de Kiev-UCR), Milan Badelj (Hamburgo-ALE), Ivan
>   Mocinic (Rijeka-CRO), Mario Pasalic (Hajduk Split-CRO) e Sammir
>   (Getafe-ESP)
>
> Atacantes: Mario Mandzukic (Bayern de Munique-ALE), Nikica Jelavic
>   (Hull City-ING), Ivica Olic (Wolfsburg-ALE), Eduardo da Silva
>   (Shakhtar Donetsk-UCR), Duje Cop (Dínamo Zagreb-CRO), Ivo Ilicevic
>   (Hamburgo-ALE), Ivan Perisic (Wolfsburg-ALE) e Ante Rebic
>   (Fiorentina-ITA)
>
> Técnico: Niko Kovac (CRO)

Comment: How do you want to parse the data?  What do you want the data to look like after parsing (i.e., classes, another text file, etc)?  Also, you don't need to post the entire text document, just a representative sample that will let us see the format.

Comment: Please don't put the whole text here, use a paragraph or so and put the rest on PasteBin or similar. With that being said, you are likely going to run into some Natural Language Processing (NLP) problems.

Comment: You doin't need to post the entire text, also what have you tried and how are you stuck?

Comment: I know I can use some Split in C#, but I would like to hear from you experts another way of doing this.

Comment: Show your own effort first.

Comment: My effort is a code that uses Split.

Comment: So show it. And tell us how it doesn't do the job.

Comment: Man, I am not beginner, I know how to "do the job". I wanted another best way to do this kind of task...

Comment: Without seeing what you've already tried and knowing how it falls short, you're really limiting your chances of getting a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex.

Select everything after : or , and before (

Update:

The C# library gives you a way to match strings. I would imagine you want to use this method [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It will return a list of strings back and you can iterate over that, or use string.join to crunch them all down into a single line.

Comment: The last player name, is separated by " e ", instead of a ", "

Comment: So it's separated by **either** `, ` **or** ` e `.

Comment: Too vague, doesn't hint at the structure to be filled

Answer (score 1):

If you define the rules for the structure of the test that will help. So:

Define your data structures - it looks like it could be base on the following, where the class Players consist of position. player name, club name

```
public class myFootballData
{
    public string CountryName
    public List<Players>
}
```

- Process the data on a line by line basis iterating through either a data file or a string. If a string then split it into an array on a newline.
- If a line is blank then ignore
- If a line has no colons or brackets then it starts a new myFootBall object with the country name
- Split the following non-country lines on : and then { to give the position, name and club

This is a pointer to a solution, not a fully worked solution. Still needs your input to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a regular expression that captures the text between the colon/comma and the parenthesis with lazy quantifiers like...

```
[:|,](.*?)[(].*?[)]
```

That should get you started.